# Querying Contacts DB w/ multiple synced accounts in Android

Tags: android, cursor, google-contacts-api

My Android app has a ContactsList activity in which I simply display a list of contacts that are on the phone.

Only recently I noticed that my activity only displays contacts synced with my main Google account. I have two Google accounts on my test phone and ideally I want my activity to display the contacts for both accounts (or multiple accounts).

How do I query across multiple accounts?

This is how I setup my cursor currently

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phones.CONTENT_URI, null,
            queryString, null, Phones.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    startManagingCursor(c);
```

On a side note, I know android.provider.contacts.phones is deprecated and I should be using ContactsContract but I need to build my app with SDK 1.5, which doesn't have ContactsContract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue to use the deprecated Contacts APIs but they only work with the first Google account assigned to the phone- they will not work with multiple accounts, as noted in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html).

Comment: you're right. my solution was to build my project with 2.0 and use ContactsContract or the deprecated API depending on what OS it runs on. worked nicely.